# plotting points with list logical comparison

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a file containing 6 columns. I want to separate some parts of this file and then plot them so I have read them by numpy and defining empty space to store the points which I needed. To fill the array I have defined a condition then filling array. I faced an error of

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-c74d3cae8a8a> in <module>
     23 for i in range(1,len(x)):
     24 
---> 25     if (near == 0.0  or near>=0.0):
     26         xx.append(x[i])
     27         yy.append(y[i])

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

the code that I have written is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.loadtxt('file_1001.out')
near = a[-1]
x = a[0]
y = a[1]
#print(most_frequent(near))
xx=[]
yy=[]

for i in range(1,len(x)):

    if (near == 0.0  or near>=0.0):
        xx.append(x[i])
        yy.append(y[i])

print(xx)
print(yy)
```

Comment: replace or with |. what happens?

Comment: Can you tell the shape of the arrays?

Comment: @techytushar the shape depends on the number of points meet the condition, I mean if the number of points was 1200, the shape becomes `(1200,)`

Comment: @Ehsan I have done but it did not solve the problem

Comment: if (near == 0.0  or near>=0.0): this is equal to if (near>=0.0): . what now?

Comment: @Ehsan it got this error `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` like before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using `all()` since `near` seems to be a list:

```
for i in range(1,len(x)):
    if all(ii>=0.0 for ii in near):
        xx.append(x[i])
        yy.append(y[i])
```

Comment: your solution was correct about the error that I have gotten. But it's still a problem to catch the array. I mean I could not exclude the coordination of the points. `xx.append(x[i]) and yy.append(y[i])` does not take any value from out initial array